# How can I connect Wix custom database to my app using http functions?

Tags: android, velo

How Can I connect wix data base to my android app using wix http functions ?

Comment: Question is too broad. What code are you using? What error are your receiving? Read the documentation which outlines how to expose a site's API using http: https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/wix-http-functions.html

Comment: Currently I am Using Java & Javascript respectively To Connect But Am Confused how to implement the Wix api correctly in Android Java file.

Answer (score 0):

If you can give more detail on where you got stuck it will be more easy to help you :)

if you are starting from the beginning you can use these resources to start

https://support.wix.com/en/article/corvid-exposing-a-site-api-with-http-functions
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tYMq5dfgb3w